# sprockets dont want to compile valid coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sprockets, middleman

```
@element.stop().animate
  scrollLeft: @left
  scrollTop:  @top
, @options.duration, "linear"
```

it compiles in online interpreter (coffeescript.org) to:

```
this.element.animate({
  scrollLeft: this.left,
  scrollTop: this.top
}, this.options.duration, "linear");
```

But middleman (it uses sprockets) throws an exception about "." in "@options.duration":

```
Uncaught Error: ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: Parse error on line 131:
Unexpected '.' (in */source/javascripts/views/scene.js.coffee) application.js:1
(anonymous function)
```

I am new to coffee script. Does it look like bug in sprockets?

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing tabs and spacing? Try variations of `.animate { ... }, @options.duration, 'linear'` to see what happens (the braces are *optional*, not *forbidden*).

Comment: you are right. There was 1 tab before this line! post your comment as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error could happen if you're accidentally mixing tabs and spaces in your CoffeeScript. You probably won't be able to see the problem with your eyes and the copy/paste you're doing to check your work at coffeescript.org could convert the tab to spaces behind your back.